# How can I render tags from Rich Text Editor in Prismic React Client?

Tags: reactjs, richtextbox, rich-text-editor, prismic.io

I am Working on a Prismic React Project, In which I need a functionality to show tooltip from rich text editor which is expected to show from the nested tags in Rich Text editor.
A little bit help will be of lot of beneficial to us.

This is the functionality I want, but this is not specific how many times and where we need to show this thing in the whole project:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom [HTMLSerializer](https://prismic.io/docs/technologies/html-serializer-reactjs) and a library for tooltips. Here’s an example where I used the `react-tooltip`[(npm link)](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-tooltip)

The serializer will detect the text and wrap it in a paragraph tag; then, it will use the label as the `data-for` and `id` attributes and the tooltip content itself in the `<ReactTooltip />` component.

```
import React from 'react'
import { Elements } from 'prismic-reactjs'
import ReactTooltip from 'react-tooltip'

export const htmlSerializer = function (type, children, element, content) {
  switch (type) {
    case Elements.label:
      const label = children.data.label ? children.data.label : ''
      console.log(content.join(''))
      return (
        <span>
          <p data-tip data-for={label}>
            {content.join('')}
          </p>
          <ReactTooltip id={label} place="top" effect="solid">
            {label}
          </ReactTooltip>
        </span>
      )

      // ... here goes the rest of your HTML serializer confguration
    default:
      return null
  }
}
```

After that, I passed it to my Rich Text field.

```
import { htmlSerializer } from '../utils/htmlSerializer'

<RichText render={document.data.text_field} htmlSerializer={htmlSerializer} />
```

Then, you'd just need to style it as you like. Here's a preview of how the component looks like:
[image]